# Detect 360° iOS device rotation using gyroscope

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gyroscope

I want my app to be able to detect a device rotation while the device is held horizontally. I could use readings from a compass but I believe yaw values from the gyroscope would be more accurate. Given yaw readings, what would be the best algorithm to determine a 360° rotation (either clockwise or counter-clockwise). And it has to be a full 360°, not just turning the phone 180° in one direction and back 180° in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea assuming that you can obtain the readout in short intervals, and that the yaw can be zeroed at a specific start point. This is different from the other answer, which detects full circles from a continuously adapted start point.

In this approach, we keep comparing the current yaw to the previous yaw, asking whether a checkpoint at 180 degrees, or `PI` has been passed. Initially, the checkpoint flag `cp_pi` is `NO`, and passing it in either direction toggles its state. Note that yaw changes its sign in two places, at the zero point and again at `PI` to `-PI`.

Assuming your object has two properties that are persistent between `tick`s of the detector, `BOOL cp_pi;` and `float prev_yaw;`, we consider that `d_yaw` is less than `PI` for crossing 0 and larger than `PI` for crossing at the opposite end of your circle. When crossing the opposite end, we toggle `cp_pi`. When `cp_pi` is `YES` while crossing 0, we are guaranteed to have passed a full circle - since otherwise, `cp_pi` would have been toggled back to `NO`:

```
-(void)tick
{
    float yaw = [self zeroedYaw];
    if ((fabs(yaw) == PI) || (yaw == 0.0f)) return;

    if (yaw * prev_yaw < 0)
    {
        float d_yaw = fabs(yaw - prev_yaw);
        if (d_yaw > PI)
        {
            cp_pi = ! cp_pi;
        }
        else if (cp_pi)
        {
            // fire detection event
        }
    }
    prev_yaw = yaw;
}
```

Note that in order to make our life easier, we skip the detector function entirely if `yaw` is sitting right on one of the checkpoints.

Comment: What if I cross 180° in one direction, and then turn back 180° in the opposite direction toward 0? Will it still count as a rotation?

Comment: It would be be fine, because `cp_pi = ! cp_pi` will flip back to `NO` on the second crossing, so it would not be detected as a rotation.

Comment: If you then turn around another time to complete the full circle, `cp_pi` will flip to `YES` again at +/- `PI`, and the event would eventually trigger at 0. So only full circles will count.

Comment: Hey a really nice solution.. plz can u tell what does `zeroedYaw` do?

Comment: @AbmedZ., `zeroedYaw` must return a yaw angle between `-PI` and `PI` and that is zeroed around the initial yaw.

Answer (score 3):

You would use CoreMotion to get the rotation about the vertical axis. You need to add the delta of rotation events. Every time more than a minimal value is in a different direction than the previous you reset your starting point. Then when you arrive at either plus or minus 360 degrees from this start point you have the rotation.

Comment: Yes, CoreMotion uses a combination of the gyroscope and compass to give a more precise and accurate reading of the device orientation.